# ActiveRecord Build or Create method requiring passing parent object in as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

It was my understanding that the build/create method on child object within a model would automatically create the relationship.

However, while I use a `validates` on both the parent and child object, I can't save the parent object, unless I explicitly pass in the parent object in the child build/create method

**Parent Class**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tax, :total
  has_many :order_lines

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :order_lines , presence: true
end
```

**Child Class**

```
class OrderLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order, :product, :qty
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  ...
  ...
  validates :order, presence: true
end
```

**PROBLEM**

So I get errors if I try to:

```
order.order_lines.build(product: product)
order.save => #error for order_lines, order can't be blank

#or
order.order_lines.create(product: product) => # throws same error
```

But I can do the following successfully:

```
order.order_lines.build(product: product, order: order)
order.save => #true

#or
order.order_lines.create(product: product, order: order) => #true
```

This causes me further problems with FactoryGirl and creating tests.

Am I wrong and misunderstanding that you have to explicitly pass in the parent object?

Rails vs: 3.2.11

[AR API documenation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The associations in rails are supposed to make your life easier, not the opposite.

What about something like this?

```
Order has_many Lines has_one Product
```

That architecture makes more sense to me. Now you could do something like this:

```
order.lines.product.build(attributes)
```

Comment: Thanks dr4ke, but that doesn't address whether or not I should not have to pass in the parent object with the create/build method.  Also, your suggestion would break the domain logic that an orderline can only have one product association.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. You do it my way and your model associations should build properly, validate accordingly, and test easily. Maybe I missed the point?